# Selecting Greatest N records in X groups

Tags: mysql, grouping, greatest-n-per-group

So I've been running through all the questions under the greatest-n-per-group tag, and either I don't understand what I'm reading, or nothing has fit my needs so far.  [This link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) has also  provided a lot of useful information, but still no answer.

So I've got a table with the following fields:

- id (unique int)
- user_id (int)
- category (varchar)
- score (int)
- interest (int)

I believe my problem strays from the common greatest-n-per-group question, in that I don't need the greatest N for *every* group.  I need the greatest N records for X groups.

So, I need to get X categories with the highest interest (simple, GROUP BY category ORDER BY interest, LIMIT X).  And then I need to get N records with the highest score for each of those categories.

How would my query look for something like this?

*Sorry if this is really a duplicate of every other greatest-n-per-group question, and I just don't understand how they work.  Feel free to close this if so.*

### Update:

Per @tehshrike's prodding, here's a bit more information.

Really what's happening is that my user's have `interest` in lots of different `categories`.  I would like to generate a list of users with the highest `score` in the `categories` that the original user is `interested` in.

So one possible thing that I'm looing for is:

The 15 users with the highest `score` in the 4 `categories` that user 1 is most `interested` in.

---

For a **specific user_id** find Top X categories (with highest interest for that specific user) and for those (X categories) find Top N users (with highest score for those categories).

Comment: "So, I need to get X categories with the highest interest (simple, ORDER BY interest, LIMIT X)." What if the same category occurs multiple times in the result set?

Comment: What is the primary key of this table?  Does it have any other unique keys?

Comment: @TehShrike Sorry about that.  There is a unique ID field.  Didn't include it cause I didn't think it was relevant.  Question edited.

Comment: @MarkByers I figured there was an implied GROUP BY in that statement, so you get the top X groups (grouped by the category).

Comment: @jwegner So there can be more than one record with the same category or user?  When you talk about about the "highest interest", what do you mean - the category with the single highest interest record, the category with the highest total interest, or something else?

Comment: @TehShrike Correct.  There will never be two records with the same category AND user, but there will be multiple records with the same category, and multiple records with the same user.

Comment: @jwegner All right, so you have a unique key on user_id,category.  That's good to know.  Now, can you define what you mean when you talk about finding the highest interest per... something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3909/discussion-between-tehshrike-and-jwegner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT catX.category
       catX.interest
       t1.user_id
       t1.score
FROM 
    ( SELECT category 
           , interest 
      FROM tableX 
      WHERE user_id = @user_id_we_are_interested_in     --- specific user 
      ORDER BY interest DESC
      LIMIT @X                         --- top @X categories per specific user 
    ) AS catX 
  JOIN 
    tableX AS t1 
      ON t1.category = catX.category 
  LEFT JOIN 
    tableX AS t2 
      ON  t2.category = t1.category 
      AND t2.score > t1.score 
  GROUP BY t1.category
         , t1.user_id
  HAVING COUNT(t2.score) < @N                      --- top @N users per category 
  ORDER BY catX.interest DESC 
         , t1.score DESC
```

Comment: This seems to be just about what I want.. just a couple weird things.  First off, I changed the < on the HAVING line to a <=..  Seems to work better.  Also, it seems like the query is trying to look only for records with the user_id=user_id_we_are_interested_in.  So, if other_user_id has a greater score, it completely drops off that category as if it weren't there (that's what happens when N=1).  It'll continue to hide the category until N equals the number of users with higher scores than user_id_we_are_interested_in.

Comment: It's not going to work when there are users who have set the same score for a category, so if you have `N=3` and there are 5 users with same (high) score for a category, then they will be shown, all 5.

Comment: (previous comment was not true..)  It actually looks like the correct columns that I want to be seeing are t2.user_id and t2.score.  However, if there is only one record per category t2 is NULL (that's probably an easier fix).  That's my best guess so far, but occasionally I'm still getting the wrong data, like it's not selecting the highest score and skipping to the second highest sometimes...

Comment: Sorry, check the corrected version. There was something left out in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You're a freaking genious.  It works perfectly, and it's not super slow.  The only (very minor) problem is it doesn't work if `N=1`, but that's not really that big of an issue.  There aren't many good reasons that I would need to run a query where `N=1`.  Thank you.  If I could +10 you, I would.

Comment: Use the `COUNT(*) < @N`, not `<=`

Comment: Yeah, I changed back to that.  Still getting no records when `N=1`.  No worry though, I'll never run that query.

Comment: I wonder how that would happen (not showing rows for N=0). Are there NULLs in some columns, like the `score` perhaps?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3928/discussion-between-jwegner-and-ypercube)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write your groupwise-max query, and then limit it down by JOINing on something like this:

```
JOIN
(
  SELECT category
  FROM your_table
  ORDER BY interest
  LIMIT 10
) AS just_get_these_categories ON just_get_these_categories.category = your_table.category
```

(This is assuming that category is a candidate key in your table)

Edit: based on further questions, it looks like what you want is not possible.  (See: [chatlog](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/3909))

Comment: That's actually exactly what I've done so far.  That works perfectly to get the 4 categories that we're looking at, but now I'm lost on getting the greatest-n for each of those categories.

Comment: Not sure if you're still following this thread, but @ypercube got the answer above - it's really a pretty cool query.  Thanks again for the help!