# MySQL $i++ equivalent

Tags: mysql, sql, sequence

Query I'm using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
    SUM(amount) AS amount,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(added, '%W (%e/%m)') AS daily
FROM affiliates_earnings
WHERE added >= '1319074836'
    AND added <= '1319679636'
GROUP BY daily
```

Output:

```
+----------+--------+-------------------+
| COUNT(*) | amount | daily             |
+----------+--------+-------------------+
|        1 |    195 | Tuesday (25/10)   |
|        4 |    470 | Wednesday (26/10) |
+----------+--------+-------------------+
```

What I would like to show up:

```
+-------+----------+--------+-------------------+
| i     |COUNT(*)  | amount | daily             |
+-------+----------+--------+-------------------+
| 1     |        1 |    195 | Tuesday (25/10)   |
| 2     |        4 |    470 | Wednesday (26/10) |
+-------+----------+--------+-------------------+
```

Essentially `i` would be the sequential number (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6...).

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Iterate in your target environment when you pull from the recordset.

Comment: Check this posting:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I'm trying to generate some flot charts.

Comment: @MeisamMulla: That doesn't answer my question at all, nor does it preclude heeding my advice!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal basically I'm trying to generate the following using smarty:

[i, value], [i, value], [i, value] etc. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @MeisamMulla: Yes. The way I told you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without ROW_NUMBER(), you can fake it [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870227/mysql-select-top-n-rows-out-of-m-groups/7870891#7870891) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql/904110#904110):

```
  SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i, COUNT(*), ...
    FROM affiliates_earnings
    JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) dummy
   WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing this is almost nonsense,　but if your really want, try this way:

```
SELECT 
    @i:=@i+1 as i,
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(a.amount) AS amount,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(a.added, '%W (%e/%m)') AS daily
FROM affiliates_earnings a, (SELECT @i:=0) b
WHERE a.added >= '1319074836'
    AND a.added <= '1319679636'
GROUP BY a.daily
```